# Move all script tags from the document into the head tag with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am using XSLT with a couple of XML files to generate my web page. I want to be able to add a `<widget name="example" />` widget tag in my XML, which inserts a widget into the corresponding place in the html. This widget is also defined by an XML file, which defines its html contents and other info.

This goes pretty well, but now the widget needs one or more scripts, which it defines like

```
<scripts>
    <script>jquery<script>
    <script>animation</script>
</scripts>
```

I want to add this script to the head tag of the html, instead of scattering script tags all over the place. The current approach I use for this is the following: I construct my page and put it into a variable, like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="document">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="page/title" /></title>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/page/scripts" mode="content" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/page/sheets" mode="content" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="header">
                    <h1><xsl:value-of select="page/title" /></h1>
                </div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$menu/menu" mode="menu" />
                <div class="content">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="page/content/*" mode="content" />
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($document)" mode="collect-resources" />
</xsl:template>
```

This leaves the `scripts` tags where they are. After this, I call

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($document)" mode="collect-resources" />
```

which leads to the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="head" mode="collect-resources">
    <xsl:for-each select="..//scripts">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()/*" mode="scripts" /> <!-- Convert the scripts defined in this scripts tag into proper HTML script tags. -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="scripts" mode="collect-resources" /> <!-- Remove all scripts tags. -->

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="collect-resources">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()" mode="collect-resources"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Which traverses the entire document two times: one time to collect all the scripts tags to put the scripts in the header, and a second time to remove all `scripts` tags.

This becomes quite slow for larger documents and is a bit dirty. Is there a way to do this that is neater and/or quicker?

APPENDIX I - widget.xml

```
<widget>
    <scripts>
        <script>/widgets/example/main</script>
    </scripts>
    <content>
        <div class="example-widget" />
    </content>
</widget>
```

APPENDIX II - template.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="widget" mode="content">
    <xsl:variable name="path">../widgets/<xsl:value-of select="@name" />/widget.xml</xsl:variable> <!-- The path to the widget xml -->
    <xsl:variable name="widget" select="document($path)"/>
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">widget</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$widget/widget/scripts" mode="content" /> <!-- Copy the widget script information. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$widget/widget/content/*" mode="content" /> <!-- Copy the widget contents. -->
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="content"> <!-- Copy anything that is not a widget. -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()" mode="content" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You say you have a `widget` element you process but your code does not show that so it is bit difficult to understand where you really process those elements the first time and where the `script` elements end up.

Comment: This is not really about implementation details. I could drown you in my full code base, but that is not very relevant to the question. You can trust me that the `script` elements, with the rest of the widget HTML, end up several levels deep in my HTML, inside the `body` element.

Comment: But I'll add the relevant widget code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems inside your

```
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="page/title" /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/page/scripts" mode="content" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/page/sheets" mode="content" />
        </head>
```

you want to make sure you process any `widget`s and their linked scripts directly e.g.

```
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="page/title" /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/page/scripts" mode="content" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//widget" mode="script"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/page/sheets" mode="content" />
        </head>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="widget" mode="script">
    <xsl:variable name="path">../widgets/<xsl:value-of select="@name" />/widget.xml</xsl:variable> <!-- The path to the widget xml -->
    <xsl:variable name="widget" select="document($path)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$widget/widget/scripts" mode="scripts" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

and in the other template you would then not output the scripts

```
<xsl:template match="widget" mode="content">
    <xsl:variable name="path">../widgets/<xsl:value-of select="@name" />/widget.xml</xsl:variable> <!-- The path to the widget xml -->
    <xsl:variable name="widget" select="document($path)"/>
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">widget</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$widget/widget/content/*" mode="content" /> <!-- Copy the widget contents. -->
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You will have to measure whether that performs better.

Comment: Thanks! Not quite as neat as I would like, but a whole lot better, and probably subsantially faster. Thank you very much!